# How to select rows from a certain date in pandas dataframe with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with datetime as index. similar to the below one

```
>>> data.index
Index(['2019-05-15 23:45:00', '2019-05-15 23:46:00', '2019-05-15 23:47:00',
       '2019-05-15 23:48:00', '2019-05-15 23:49:00', '2019-05-15 23:50:00',
       '2019-05-15 23:52:00', '2019-05-15 23:53:00', '2019-05-15 23:54:00',
       '2019-05-15 23:55:00',
       ...
       '2019-05-19 05:36:00', '2019-05-19 05:37:00', '2019-05-19 05:38:00',
       '2019-05-19 05:39:00', '2019-05-19 05:40:00', '2019-05-19 05:41:00',
       '2019-05-19 05:42:00', '2019-05-19 05:43:00', '2019-05-19 05:44:00',
       '2019-05-19 05:45:14'],
      dtype='object', name='date', length=989)
```

I need to select all the rows which corresponding to the date `2019-05-16`. I tried these two methods.

1) `data['2019-05-16']` gives `KeyError: '2019-05-16'`

2) `data.loc['2019-05-16']` gives `KeyError: 'the label [2019-05-16] is not in the [index]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to DatetimeIndex first, because now it is string repr of datetimes:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
```

---

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(3)}, 
                     index=['2019-05-15 23:45:00','2019-05-16 23:46:00','2019-05-17 23:47:00'])

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
print(data)
                     a
2019-05-15 23:45:00  0
2019-05-16 23:46:00  1
2019-05-17 23:47:00  2
```

Your solution working, if exist at least one index value with date:

```
print (data['2019-05-16'])
                     a
2019-05-16 23:46:00  1
```

If not exist, there are alternatives:

```
print (data[data.index.normalize() == '2019-05-18'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []

print (data[data.index.floor('d') == '2019-05-18'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []

print (data[data.index.date == '2019-05-18'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []
```